# Blank-White Screen Android Emulator Xamarin App (Displays in iOS emulator correctly)

Tags: c#, android, user-interface, xamarin, prism

[View App Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLpzf.png)

I have added in a new android project to a pre-existing Xamarin app that already contains an iOS project. I am able to load the view in the iphone emulator correctly, but when I attempt to debug the android project it only displays a white screen. The app doesnt load at all. I have made successful and viewable updates to the app name and app icon. I have tried to modify things such as splash screen without success as I cant see any changes.

This is not an issue with the emulator as I have successfully ran a tabbed test Xamarin app in the emulator and it displays as it should. I probably don't have something connected as it needs to be within the android project set up to display the views pre-created in the parent project. No errors are displayed when debugging and app is not using a shell. I am aware that I may be implementing the android project incorrectly this is my first time using Xamarin. All feedback appreciated.

App.xaml.cs:

```
     public partial class App : PrismApplication
    {
        public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer = null) : base(initializer)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called when the PrismApplication has completed it's initialization process.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Start(int alertId = -1)
        {
            NavigationParameters parameters = new NavigationParameters();
            if (alertId != -1)
            {
                parameters.Add(NavigationKeys.LaunchAlertId, alertId);
            }
            this.NavigationService.NavigateAsync("my-app:///Main", parameters);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Used to register types with the container that will be used by your application. 
        /// All new views need to be registered as well as their corresponding view model.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Main, MainViewModel>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Login, LoginViewModel>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<MoreOptions, MoreOptionsViewModel>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<InternalWeb, InternalWebViewModel>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Accounts, AccountsViewModel>();
```

MainActivity.cs:

```
                {
                    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
                    {
            
                        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            
                        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
                        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
                        LoadApplication(new App(new AndroidPlatformInitializer()));
                    }
                    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
                    {
                        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            
                        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
                    }
            
            
                    public class AndroidPlatformInitializer : IPlatformInitializer
                    {
                        public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
                        {
            
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Application Output:

```
Loaded assembly: appname.Android.dll
Loaded assembly: FFImageLoading.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: FFImageLoading.Forms.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: FFImageLoading.Forms.Platform.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: FFImageLoading.Platform.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: FormsViewGroup.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics.Android.Bindings.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Microsoft.AppCenter.Android.Bindings.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes.Android.Bindings.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Microsoft.AppCenter.Distribute.Android.Bindings.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Microsoft.AppCenter.Distribute.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Microsoft.AppCenter.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Newtonsoft.Json.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Plugin.Connectivity.Abstractions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Plugin.Connectivity.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Plugin.Media.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Plugin.Toast.Abstractions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Plugin.Toast.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Prism.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Prism.Forms.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Prism.Unity.Forms.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: appname.API.dll
Loaded assembly: appname.Database.dll
Loaded assembly: appname.DependencyInterfaces.dll
Loaded assembly: appname.dll
Loaded assembly: appname.Models.dll
Loaded assembly: appname.Repository.dll
Loaded assembly: appname.ViewModels.dll
Loaded assembly: SegmentedControl.FormsPlugin.Abstractions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: SegmentedControl.FormsPlugin.Android.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: SQLite-net.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: SQLiteNetExtensions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: SQLiteNetExtensionsAsync.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_green.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: SQLitePCLRaw.core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Unity.Abstractions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Unity.Container.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.Activity.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.Annotation.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.Annotation.Experimental.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.AppCompatResources.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.Arch.Core.Common.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.Arch.Core.Runtime.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.AsyncLayoutInflater.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.CardView.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.Collection.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.Concurrent.Futures.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.ConstraintLayout.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.ConstraintLayout.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.CoordinatorLayout.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.CursorAdapter.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.CustomView.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.DocumentFile.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.DrawerLayout.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.DynamicAnimation.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.Fragment.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.Interpolator.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.Core.UI.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.Core.Utils.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.V4.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Common.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Runtime.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.ViewModel.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.ViewModelSavedState.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.Loader.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.LocalBroadcastManager.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.Media.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.MultiDex.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.Navigation.Common.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.Navigation.Runtime.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.Navigation.UI.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.Preference.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.Print.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.SavedState.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.SlidingPaneLayout.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.SwipeRefreshLayout.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.Tracing.Tracing.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.Transition.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.VectorDrawable.Animated.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.VectorDrawable.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.VersionedParcelable.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.ViewPager.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.AndroidX.ViewPager2.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Auth.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Essentials.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Google.Android.Material.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Google.Guava.ListenableFuture.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Xamarin.Plugin.Calendar.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Mono.Android.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Java.Interop.dll [External]
Resolved pending breakpoint for 'Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.RegisterJniNatives(System.IntPtr, System.Int32, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr, System.Int32)' to /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNIEnv.cs:124 [0x00000].
Loaded assembly: System.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Mono.Security.dll [External]
```

Comment: a good approach would be to create a new Forms app using them same template, but including both iOS and Android.  Then compare the Android config and startup between the two apps to see if there are any differences.  Or, compare the Android project from one of the Prism sample apps

Comment: Thank you Jason! This was my first thought. I combed through everything but im not seeing any differences at all within the file structures.

Comment: not just the structure, what about the Android project files?  And you should probably tag with `Prism` if you want to catch the attention of those folks

Comment: The android project files have all the references linked from the parent project to the individual viewmodel etc folders the same as ios. I feel as though Im missing something between the android app and actually linking it with the layout of the parent especially since the splash screen ive implemented wont even show up.

Comment: I'm not a PRISM guy so I have no idea.  Have you actually looked at the **code** and compared it?  Are you doing all the necessary setup and initialization for Android?  I notice you have still not updated the tags to include PRISM.

Comment: What's `"my-app:///Main"` supposed to do? And who calls `Start`, anyway?

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys, the project Im building onto was using that start method following on initialized for some kind of alert set up. I implemented the resources I needed to call the start function, then called the start function and the views from the parent were inherited causing the app to actually load :)